# show 'time out:30000ms implicit error' in selenium IDE while i run the test cases, How to solve it?

Tags: timeout, selenium-ide, implicit

I use selenium IDE and every time show the 'Implicit Wait timed out after 30000ms' error,i hear 'setTimeout(timeout)' command but no idea how and where to set this command,so please give me a solution of this command

Comment: Yes, got same error i used kantu selenium.

Comment: my error code lines:

{
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "/html/body/div/aside/section/ul[2]/li[2]/a/span",
      "Value": ""
    },
{
      "Command": "click",
      "Target": "link=Users",
      "Value": ""
    },